# Слишком большое количество соединений при запросах к БД в JPA Hibernate и БД перестает работать

Tags: java, база-данных, jpa, jsf

Я создал веб-приложение на JSF и при заполнении формы вызывается управляемый бин и делает запрос к бд и добавляет новую запись,а так же при загрузке страницы выводит содержимое БД.
Однако, при осуществлении запросов создается чрезмерно большое количество запросов к бд и через несколько итераций добавлений записей количество соединений становится слиишком большим и  БД перестает работать.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Что же вы там такого написали? Какая БД?

Comment: Где можно посмотреть код?

Comment: Postgress и Oracle были

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы вызываете `openSession`, значит вам нужно в дальнейшем её закрывать. Если хотите получить сессию в границах контекста используйте `getCurrentSession`.

---

[Hibernate openSession() vs getCurrentSession()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046662/hibernate-opensession-vs-getcurrentsession)